# Why run IIS Express locally?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express

I'm currently reading the documentation about asp.net core. But this [page about servers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html) got me a little confused. As far as I understand is that ASP.NET Core applications are just console applications which are starting a http server. A http server like IIS can be used as reversed proxy.

I assume that is for performance reasons. Why would I run IIS express locally during development? Its not that I need real performance there? Is it because IIS is more feature rich? Which features work better in IIS?

Comment: Well, one of the reasons is that the WebListener/Kestrel variants doesn't support SSL, at least not easily and secure (you'll need private key password in either config, source or secret store), whereas IIS uses the already imported certificates from certificate store  and one of the most common scenarios is to run the application behind iis als reverse proxy, which comes close to what IIS is doing (using the ASP.NET Core Module for IIS) and redirecting the trafic to the kestrel server behind

Answer (score 1):

> > Why would I run IIS express locally during development?

Pure convenience. IIS Express comes with Visual Studio. F5 or ^F5 and IIS Express is launched.

Comment: Should also mention that IIS Express has been there for years and really no need to surprise users with another thing without good reasons.

Comment: I thought why adding the extra 'complexity' of running 2 http servers at the same time. As an experienced developer it feels convenient, but as a new developer it involves learning something about iis..

Answer (score 0):

What server you run in development depends on which server you're planning on deploying with in production.

If you will be deploying your ASP.NET Core application to Linux or otherwise plan on using Kestrel with a reverse proxy like nginx, you should test with Kestrel locally in development.

If you will be deploying to a Windows Machine and IIS, you should test with IIS Express locally in development.

For simple applications, I've found there isn't much difference in ASP.NET Core features when running locally on Kestrel or IIS Express. I'm mostly interested in testing to make sure it works with the server I'm planning to deploy to.

Comment: Even when running with IIS Express you run on Kestrel, because there only two supported ways to host ASP.NET Core applications: WebListener or Kestrel (Helios was abandoned). WebListener only runs on Windows, so the natural choice is to run Kestrel

Comment: @Tseng Ah, TIL. Thanks for clarifying.